# Copy/paste from attached tutorial

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I have just faced the following dilema on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608113/how-to-override-activitys-fullscreen-exit-gesture) topic. What should I do, when user gives an answer which's half is pasted from a tutorial which he mentions in this answer, but doesn't quote it. In my opinion it's plagiarism because the credits for that certain part of his answer aren't clear, but on the other hand it'd be perfect answer if only `>` was added to his answer so it'd be a pity to remove this answer.

Which of the following options should I follow?

- Edit the answer - add `>` marks (might be problem if less then 6 characters edited),
- Comment that it's plagiarism,
- Ignore,
- Flag as plagiarism - what reason,
- Downvote for plagiarism,
- Upvote for answering the question.

I've chosen first two options but I'm not sure if it's a correct reaction.

**EDIT:**

According to the discussion in the comments it seems, that the proper reaction is to `downvote` and `flag for moderator attention` providing good description - e.g. original source.

Comment: I'd downvote and flag as plagiarism. Answers that consist of only a quote aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow even when properly attributed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Plagiarism [beta]! Take the tour, and join us in chat.

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's not only a quote.

Comment: It's still not a useful Stack Overflow answer. Answers are expected to be self-contained. (And the user is a serial plagiarist - they usually don't do this only once. Going through his answers right now...)

Comment: Why shouldn't I flag this answer then?

Comment: I don't know? I think you should flag it.

Comment: Good find! He's not even above plagiarizing other SO answers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38569821/

Comment: Which flag reason would be appropriate?

Comment: In such cases, Flag for Moderator attention and explain that the contribution is plagiarism. Also add a link the the original source.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just came across a similar case when someone posted code snippet as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611039/how-to-display-xls-csv-file-as-table-in-angularjs-js) that look pretty much the same is the code in this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm) - I'm not ure if it's legitimate or not, because it's just a piece of code, and not the description (But the answer itself is very low-quality, no doubt about it)

Comment: @Alon yeah, that's plagiarism, too - on top of everything else that is wrong with that answer.

Comment: "flag for moderator attention providing good description - e.g. original source." And yet you *still* did not provide links to the source in your flags, why?

Comment: @BoltClock Because the one you're talking about was flagged before. I provided one for later flags. Shame on me